# Center placeholder string in NSSearchField after it was changed

Tags: cocoa, nssearchfield

I have a NSSearchField in UI with a placeholderString. By default its value is Search and it is centered automaticaly. But when user change selection in the sidebar I replace placeholder string with "Search in {NAME OF SIDEBARITEM}". For example:

[image]

As you can see placeholder string is not centered anymore. It will be centered after this search field activated and then deactivated.

Ho do I force NSSearchField to reposition placeholder string after it was changed?

Comment: @Pol I found a better workaround :) see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working solution I fond is to set search field's `stringValue` to some non-empty value and then to previously set value like so right after placeholder was changes:

```
@IBAction func setPlaceholder(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.searchField.placeholderString = self.inputField.stringValue
    let currentSearchStringValue = self.searchField.stringValue
    self.searchField.stringValue = "-"
    self.searchField.stringValue = currentSearchStringValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `[searchField setNeedsLayout:YES]` after setting the placeholder string.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I'm currently using is to add some whitespace padding to all placeholder strings so they are roughly the same size.